# Question on alternating least squares

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, least-squares

I have been given following problem
$$
\min _{\mathbf{x}_2 \in \mathbb{R}^k}\left(\min _{\mathbf{x}_1 \in \mathbb{R}^n}\left\|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{B} \mathbf{x}_2\right\|_2^2\right)
$$
where $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $\mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times k}$. Suppose that $\mathbf{A}$ has full column rank, and $\mathbf{P}_{\mathbf{A}}^{\perp} \mathbf{B}$ has full column rank. Using Least Squares $\mathrm{x}^*$ solution to the above problem is
$$
\mathbf{x}_2^*=\left(\mathbf{B}^T \mathbf{P}_A^{\perp} \mathbf{B}\right)^{-1} \mathbf{B}^T \mathbf{P}_{\mathbf{A}}^{\perp} \mathbf{y}
$$

How does one go about solving this problem?

One approach I thought of is to optimize over $\mathbf{x}_1$ first giving

$$\mathbf{x}_1^* = (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{B}\mathbf{x}_2)^\dagger \mathbf{A}$$

But this doesn't seem to be taking me anywhere help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you stack the vectors and solve the least-squares problem in one go?

Comment: Well you could write $Ax_1 + Bx_2$ as
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Comment: This gives the LS solution of y as: 
\begin{equation}\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} AA + BB \end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \end{bmatrix}*y\end{equation} 

How would go about now?

Comment: Are you even sure it makes sense to use least-squares?  Is $m$ larger than $k+n$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes, since it is specified that $\mathbf{P}_{\mathbf{A}}^{\perp} \mathbf{B}$ is full collumn rank, so inverse exists, right?

Comment: I took the optimization approach took the gradients w.r.t $x_1$ and $x_2$ to get 

\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        x_1 \\ 
        x_2 
    \end{bmatrix}
    = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
        A^TA & A^TB \\ 
        B^TA & B^TB 
    \end{bmatrix} ^{-1}*\begin{bmatrix}
        A^Ty \\ 
        B^Ty 
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation} 

whose solution is $$x_2 = A^{T} A \left(A^{T} A B^{T} A - B^{T} A A^{T} A\right)^{-1} B^{T} y - B^{T} A \left(A^{T} A B^{T} A - B^{T} A A^{T} A\right)^{-1} A^{T} y -(1)$$

But I'm not sure if it is the actual given